# Логирование ошибок

Tags: java, android, логирование

Здравствуйте!

Не подскажете, каким способом логировать ошибки в Android-приложениях?
Каким способом лучше отправлять с аппарата на сервер разработчика сообщения об ошибке в приложении?

Я думаю, что стоит писать все в файл и отправлять на сервер через время, если есть необходимость. Но как отловить все ошибки в приложении, пока не знаю.

Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для отлова есть библиотека Acra. Отлавливает абсолютно всё + есть возможность для отправки баг репорта программисту-создателю. [Вот мини-гайд](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123542/).

А для логирования slf4j, правда, как она дружит/недружит с андроидом, я хз.

Comment: поддерживаю,
можно даже настроить автомат. отправку отчетов об ошибках в гугл формы

Answer (score 2):

Я рекомендую [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com). Есть возможность кидать сообщения об исключениях, фатальных ошибках и т.д. Есть возможность создавать команды, давать роли: программисты, тестеры. В общем, очень удобный аналог Test Flight (iOS) только для Android.